# Application z order issue

Tags: delphi, vcl

This may not be an issue with my App (XE7) as it only occurs on 1 of my clients workstations however i would like to confirm that I am coding this properly and ask for any  guidance on resolving it

What happens is that from the apps main form a no of non modal forms may be launched and then when the last one of these is subsequently closed places the  applications main  form at the back of the Windows Z order

Here is my startup code for the main app

```
Application.Initialize;
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
Application.CreateForm(TDM, DM);
Application.CreateForm(TfmMain, fmMain);
Application.CreateForm(TfmReportDefn, fmReportDefn);
Application.Run;
```

Here is an example of the  code to launch the Non modal forms

```
  if (fmCustomer = nil) then
     fmCustomer := TfmCustomer.Create(nil);
  else
    fmCustomer.SetFocus;
```

And here is the onclose event code for the non modal form

```
procedure TfmCustomer.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  action := cafree;
  fmCustomer := nil;
end;
```

Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 0):

> Here is an example of the code to launch the Non modal forms
>
> ```
> if (fmCustomer = nil) then
>   fmCustomer := TfmCustomer.Create(nil);
> else
>   fmCustomer.SetFocus;
> ```

I would suggest something more like this instead:

```
if (fmCustomer = nil) then
  fmCustomer := TfmCustomer.Create(Application);
fmCustomer.Show;
```

First, assigning an Owner ensures the Form is still freed automatically if the app is closed and the user has not closed the Form yet.

Second, use `Show()` instead of `SetFocus()` to ensure the Form is actually visible and brought to the foreground.

> And here is the onclose event code for the non modal form
>
> ```
> procedure TfmCustomer.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
> begin
>   action := cafree;
>   fmCustomer := nil;
> end;
> ```

Using `caFree` is fine, but I would suggest moving the `nil` assignment into the `OnDestroy` event instead:

```
procedure TfmCustomer.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TfmCustomer.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fmCustomer := nil;
end;
```

The `OnClose` event will only be triggered if the user closes the window manually, if the OS is being shutdown, or if your code calls `fmCustomer.Close()`.  If the Form is ever freed for any reason other than that, you still need to `nil` the pointer, but `OnClose` wouldn't be called.